# Exception pages in development mode take upwards of 15-30 seconds to render, why is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, activerecord

I am using Rails 3 beta 4 and for some reason I have each exception taking 15-30 seconds to show. Here is my trace:

```
Started GET "/something/something/approvals/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jun 24 21:17:12 -0400 2010
  SQL (1.8ms)  describe `approvals_users`
  SQL (24.6ms)  describe `clients_users`
  SQL (1.4ms)  describe `agencies_users`
  SQL (1.2ms)  describe `clients_users`
  SQL (1.2ms)  describe `approvals_users`
  SQL (1.7ms)  describe `permissions_users`
  Processing by ApprovalsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"tricked", "client_id"=>"deez-nutz"}
  SQL (1.4ms)  describe `agencies_users`
  Agency Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `agencies`.* FROM `agencies` WHERE (`agencies`.`subdomain` = 'subdomain') LIMIT 1
  Plan Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `plans`.* FROM `plans` WHERE (`plans`.`id` = 3) LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 93ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/approval.rb:38:in `state'
  app/models/approval.rb:38:in `state'
  app/controllers/approvals_controller.rb:10:in `new'
  app/controllers/approvals_controller.rb:10:in `new'

Rendered /Users/garrett/.bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/rails-07b08721a226ff01f983e61d99ab4da96e296c97-6682cce0386811ffe3e6d31fc025ede0936d86c3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.9ms)
  SQL (2.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
Rendered /Users/garrett/.bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/rails-07b08721a226ff01f983e61d99ab4da96e296c97-6682cce0386811ffe3e6d31fc025ede0936d86c3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (21433.7ms)
Rendered /Users/garrett/.bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/rails-07b08721a226ff01f983e61d99ab4da96e296c97-6682cce0386811ffe3e6d31fc025ede0936d86c3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (21630.2ms)
```

If it helps at all, here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://gemcutter.org'

# Core
# gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta4'
gem 'rails', :git => 'http://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'memcache-client'
gem 'system_timer'
gem 'mime-types', :require => 'mime/types'
gem 'json'
gem 'haml', '~> 3.0.12'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'juicer'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'
gem 'braintree'
gem 'panda'

# Templating
gem 'liquid', '2.0.0'

# Users
gem 'warden'
gem 'ruby-openid', :require => 'openid'
gem 'canable'
gem 'devise'

# Paperclip
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/dewski/paperclip.git', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'delayed_job', :git => 'git://github.com/dewski/delayed_job.git'

group :test do
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'hpricot'
  gem 'mocha', :require => false
end
```

If I create a new Rails app, error pages show instantly. In the Rails source code, the method that has `SHOW TABLES` is `structure_dump` in `schema_statements.rb`. I searched my bundler directory for any sort of call to this method and it's not showing anything. What gives and how could this be caused to were `SHOW TABLES` is called over and over again and possibly making it so every method makes it pain to debug?

Comment: Have you a rescue_from or something like that in your controller ?

Comment: I do, but even when I take them out it doesn't change the length of the response.

Comment: It's a long-shot, but I'm used to missing DNS entries being a common culprit when 30-second errors are the symptom. I notice a 127.0.0.1 in your error log (top line) -- perhaps the system was attempting to reverse-resolve the IP to name. Does /etc/hosts have a `127.0.0.1 localhost` line?

If all else fails, you can bring a bazooka to the show: on Linux you can strace or ltrace the rails instance handling the request. On Mac OS X you can use ktrace/kdump to get system calls, no idea on library calls. It'll be a HUGE pile of information, but it will document the missing 30 seconds.

Comment: My /etc/hosts file has `127.0.0.1 localhost` in it, that was already there.

Comment: Hackish, but you could put `raise "this"` at the top of your controller action and see if the delay is before or after that, then adjust to try to find the offending line.  Does it happen in other controllers?  Other actions?  Have you tried the latest rails from git to see if it was framework related and already fixed?

Comment: @wesgarrison: I am using the latest rails from master. It raises the error just like the others and is just as slow.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I never did figure it out, it's a shame :( By chance, how big is your app? Is it relatively small or is it fairly large?

Comment: I added a bounty on this as the same problem is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 20):

We've run into this problem at our company, and while we wait for an official Rails point release, have put together a hack. The key issue, as mentioned in the Lighthouse ticket linked in the other answer, seems to be that for some apps, `request.env` contains some objects whose `#inspect` output is HUGE (like, megabytes of text), and this output all gets put into the error page.

So here it is:

```
# development.rb

config.after_initialize do    
  module SmallInspect
    def inspect
      "<#{self.class.name} - tooooo long>"
    end
  end
  [ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::RemoteIpGetter, OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook, ActionController::Base, Warden::Proxy].each do |klazz|
    klazz.send(:include, SmallInspect)
  end
end
```

The classes listed are the main culprits for us; yours will vary depending on your app.

Comment: Yeah that worked for me great. I'll leave the bounty open for now to attract the attention of anyone passing. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect.. I was about to post on same line.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a ticket for a similar issue in the rails project: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/5027

I have the same issue in my test suite and haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: This was my ticket. Is this a large application? New application?

Comment: I also noticed all models that are loaded before the exception, get the `SHOW TABLES` call.

Comment: Garrett, are you using mysql2? Can you post a backtrace from the method where the show tables is being run?

Comment: I got the backtrace here: https://github.com/ajh/show_tables/blob/master/README by adding this code to the 'tables' method of the mysql2 adapter. `begin
          raise
        rescue
          warn ''
          $!.backtrace.each {|m| warn m}
        end`

Comment: Garrett, to answer your questions, I've created an almost vanilla rails app that repros this problem. I link to it in the rails ticket. I also see it in a large app that I'm upgrading to rails3 and its a really bad problem there because of the number of models I have and the number of exceptions generated in my test suite (broken tests as part of the upgrade). My test suite fires of thousands of 'show tables' when it reports on the exceptions.

Comment: Lighthouse is dead now, related github issue is: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1525